# How to assume the trend or equation of a excel graph

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, graphing-functions, mathematical-physics, algebraic-curves

I need to find the trend of the curves in the attached graph. What is the best way to define the trend? I am not looking for the polynomial equation. I want to define them like 'the trend is a hyperbolic or parabolic curve and we can represent the curve by a equation with some coefficients'. Any help will be appreciated.

- so far, I am thinking of a hyperbolic equation (y-a=1/x-b)

[image]

Comment: Look up articles on regression.

Comment: If you want to do an atypical regression (like hyperbolic) and you don't want to work out your estimators, I know that Mathematica will do least squares fitting numerically; however, I don't know if excel has this capability. I fear not.

Comment: Excel does not have it. I will definitely look into Mathematica.